# Show advanced custom field value in custom column (wp_list_table)

Tags: wordpress, function, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I made a custom post type named **address** and added values to it with the plugin **advanced custom fields**. I would like to display those values in a custom column in the wp-list-table.

So I managed to add a column to the custom post type(address) called **views**. With the code below.

```
add_filter('manage_edit-address_columns', 'my_columns');
function my_columns($columns) {
  $columns['views'] = 'Views';
  return $columns;
}
```

Now I wanted to fill this column (**views**) with the data from the advanced custom field wich I made and called **'reserveer_url_theater_terra'** (it's a url field) and bound to the custom post type **address**, but it just shows an empty column '**views**' without the values from **'reserveer_url_theater_terra'** field . What am I doing wrong, could someone point me in the right direction? Should I be using wpdb to get the values? Or is there somthing else I should do? Thank you in advance.

```
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'my_show_columns');
function my_show_columns($name) {
global $post;
switch ($name) {
    case 'views':
        $views = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'reserveer_url_theater_terra', true);
        echo $views;
  }
}
```

I tried using get_field as Zork suggested, but I still could not get it to work.

```
$views = get_field('reserveer_url_theater_terra', $post->ID);
```

Comment: I've two ideas on that:
1. Make sure that `add_action` is fired sometime after `init`. ACF api-calls don't work before.
2. Try using get_field() instead of get_post_meta()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question it looks like my filter, action and functions where not named properly. I did not add the custom post type(**address**) correctly(stupid) and everywhere needed. After doing so, everything started working fine. Thanks for the help.

```
add_action("manage_address_posts_custom_column",  "address_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-address_columns", "address_edit_columns");

function address_edit_columns($columns){
  $columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => "Titel",
    "theater" => "Theater",
    "plaats" => "Plaats",
    "datum" => "Datum",
);

return $columns;
 } function address_custom_columns($column){
 global $post;

 switch ($column) {
    case "theater":
        the_field('theater', $post->ID );
        break;
    case "plaats":
        the_field('plaatss', $post->ID );
        break;
    case "datum":
        the_field('datum', $post->ID );
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved for me in this way:

- name of custom post type: `address`
- name of column to display in the list: `Views`
- name of acf field: `reserveer_url_theater_terra`

---

```php
/*
 * Add columns to address post list
 */
function add_acf_columns ( $columns ) {
    return array_merge ( $columns, array ( 
      'views' => __ ( 'Views' ),
    ) );
  }
  add_filter ( 'manage_address_posts_columns', 'add_acf_columns' );


/*
 * Add columns to address post list
 */
function address_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
      case 'views':
        echo get_field('reserveer_url_theater_terra', $post_id);
        break;
    }
  }
  add_action ( 'manage_address_posts_custom_column', 'address_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```

---

[This](https://pluginrepublic.com/add-acf-fields-to-admin-columns/) article helped me a lot.