# Add checkbox value to admin column for CPT

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add the values of two Advanced Custom Fields to the WordPress admin columns for a custom post type.

I have managed to successfully add two columns, the ‘Sale or Charter’ column returns the correct value, but the ‘featured’ returns the value ‘array’ rather than ‘yes’ or blank. The first is a radio button the second is a checkbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Secondly, is it possible to actually add the checkbox in the admin column? In the same way you have a star for featured products in WooCommerce.

Alternatively adding the option to the quick edit area?

This is the code I currently have, I also tried adding

```
'featured'  => '<input type="checkbox" />',
```

in place of

```
 'featured' => __ ( 'featured' ),
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
 function add_acf_columns ( $columns ) {
   return array_merge ( $columns, array ( 
     'featured' => __ ( 'featured' ),
     'sale_or_charter'   => __ ( 'Listing Type' ) 
   ) );
 }
 add_filter ( 'manage_yachts_posts_columns', 'add_acf_columns' );
 
 

 function yachts_custom_column ( $column, $post_id ) {
   switch ( $column ) {
     case 'featured':
       echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'featured', true );
       break;
     case 'sale_or_charter':
       echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'sale_or_charter', true );
       break;
   }
 }
 add_action ( 'manage_yachts_posts_custom_column', 'yachts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Refer to this answer here [Show advanced custom field value in custom column (wp_list_table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917908/show-advanced-custom-field-value-in-custom-column-wp-list-table)

Comment: That's great thanks - I scoured stack overflow for an answer but never saw this

Answer (score 0):

In the end - this amendment worked - as per the link the Bhautik posted.

Though I would be interested to know how to include the actual checkbox in the column.

```
function add_acf_columns ( $columns ) {
       return array_merge ( $columns, array ( 
         'featured' => __ ( 'featured' ),
         'sale_or_charter'   => __ ( 'Listing Type' ) 
       ) );
 }
 add_filter ( 'manage_yachts_posts_columns', 'add_acf_columns' );
 
 
 function yachts_custom_column ( $column, $post_id ) {
   
   switch ( $column ) {
     case 'featured':
        the_field('featured', $post->ID );
       break;
     case 'sale_or_charter':
        the_field('sale_or_charter', $post->ID );
       break;
   }
 }
 add_action ( 'manage_yachts_posts_custom_column', 'yachts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```